# Is there a solution to $\int_{\lambda}^{y}(x-a)^{-b}x^{-c}\exp\left( -d x^{-e} \right)dx$?

Tags: integration

I'm looking for a solution to the following integral.

$$\int_{\lambda}^{y}(x-a)^{-b}x^{-c}\exp\left( -d x^{-e} \right)dx,$$
where $b,c,d,e> 0$ and $0< a < \lambda < y$.

This equation appears in the context of Physical Layer Security, which is an area of study in digital communications (telecom).

Comment: without any further conditions (smallness of some parameters?) a closed-form solution will not be forthcoming; also note the pole at $x=a$, how is it avoided?

Comment: Dear @CarloBeenakker , do you think the additional information I've just added to the question can help solve it?

Comment: Are you looking for a closer form for the integral? for a single zero in closed form? for a an integral expression for $y$ in terms of the other variables which makes the integral zero? for something else?

Comment: Dear @MattF., I'm looking for a closed form solution.

Comment: There’s no reason to expect that a complicated integral has a closed form. So if the question stops there, I would vote to close it as not being research-level. But other questions about the integral could be appropriate, e.g.: what would you do with the closed form if you had it?

Comment: Dear @MattF., what are the other kinds of solutions we can have? If you have something in mind, please, go ahead. It might not be what I'm expecting, but might help someone else.

Comment: I think that Matt may be referring to is the following question: in what limits of your parameters are you interested? Even if there was a closed form for your integral, you are most likely interested in its behavior as certain parameters are small/large. It is not very interesting to just ask for a closed form without more mathematical context as right now your parameters are free to be located in essentially any part of a 7-dimensional hyperplane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no closed-form expression in terms of known functions, but if $a$ is small, you could use the power series in terms of the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Generalization),
$$\int_{\lambda}^{y}(x-a)^{-b}x^{-c}\exp\left( -d x^{-e} \right)\,dx=\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{b\Gamma(p+b)}{p!\Gamma(1+b)}\frac{a^p}{e}
\left[y^{-k}E_{1-k/e}\left(d y^{-e}\right)-\lambda^{-k}E_{1-k/e}\left(d \lambda^{-e}\right)\right].
$$
where $k=b+c+p-1$.

Comment: Dear. could you provide some further explanation on how you found that solution and what you mean by small "a" values, please?

Comment: I make a Taylor expansion of $(x-a)^{-b}$ in powers of $a$, then the integrand is of the form $x^{-b-c-p+1} e^{-dx^{-e}}$ and you have to sum over integers $p$; each term in the sum can be evaluated and gives the exponential integral; by "small a" I mean that series converges rapidly for $a\ll 1$, so then it is a helpful expansion (you would only need to retain a few terms)

Comment: Dear Carlo, one more question, in the exponential integral, is the subscript 1 - (k/e) or (1-k)/e? Thanks!

Comment: $1-k/e=1-(k/e)$

Comment: thanks for the clarification.